# Is it appropriate to skip salutation and just get to the point when you are replying to a potential employer?

Tags: email, salutations

So, I've been sending emails back and forth to this company regarding some job opportunities but I always find it a bit awkward as to how I'm supposed to reply to them.

Say they asked me for my contact details. Should I start with "Dear sir" or something or i should simply go "Thank you for the response, my contact details are XXXXXX"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Greetings after initial email.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164283/greetings-after-initial-email) Also [Are greetings and salutations redundant in an e-mail?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18396/) and [What is the correct greeting to use in a formal email addressed to a department/team/company?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/) And [Should I repeat my greeting in an email exchange?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/487946/)

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, why do you start a question with “So, ...“? There was no preceding thought or information and therefore the “so” is pointless.

Comment: @Anton: [Sentences beginning with “so”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43273/sentences-beginning-with-so) There are two types of people in this world - people who start conversations with ***So***, and people who find that really irritating.

Comment: You'll probably get good responses over at [workplace.se]. Here is only questions about linguistic nature of English, not really about politeness.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are correct. I just wonder why it has come to this. It used not to be so, as you might say.

Comment: @Anton:  These days, I tend to blame the *Internet* for just about everything that annoys me. My theory on *this* one is that the Internet and mobile comms / smartphones make it much easier to *start* new "conversations" (with all sorts of people all over the world, perhaps that you've never even *met* in person). And SMS / Whatsapp *text* interactions usually have no explicit "end / over and out" message. Consequently, younger people might not be so consciously aware that social interactions in general (and conversations in particular) should normally have a beginning, a middle, and an end.